# Showing that $|s_n-s| \le \varepsilon$ holds for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Find such an $n$ so that for the following series:
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}$$
>
> $|s_n-s| \le 0.001$, (where  $s$ is the sum and $s_n$ is the partial sum of the series $n$) holds true.

What are they essentially asking for here? Are we trying to prove that the partial sum converges to $s$ or what?

Answer (score 1):

For [alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series), the [approximating sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Approximating_sums) $s_n$ are bounded by the term $a_{n+1}$, i.e. $\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}$ in our case.

Therefore, for a given $\epsilon$, if your pick $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $(2n+1)! > 1/\epsilon$, you get $\vert s - s_n \vert < \epsilon$ as requested.

By the way, $s = \cos 1$.

*What is asked is to find $n$ large enough to approximate the infinite sum with enough precision, i.e. $\epsilon$*